# how to auto refresh component when redux state get updated

Tags: reactjs, redux, rerender

I currently store user name in redux store and show it in topbar after user logged in. (Shown in screenshots). However, it do not re-render automatically when redux state gets updated. I still need to do some actions in topbar then username does appear. Otherwise, it does not appear. So the question, how to force to re-render topbar component from my login component.
Another question: user name will disapprear when refresh page. So is there any option to persist data with redux state? Or it's impossible.

```html
const Login = () => {
  ...
  const handleLogin = async googleData => {
    ...
    //store user name value als application state into redux store
    store.dispatch(nameActionCreator(googleData.profileObj.name));
    ...
  }
}
```

```html
const TopBar = () => {
  ...
  return(
    ...
    <h5>store.getState().userNameRecuder.name</h5>
    ...
  )
}
```

Before login
[image: before]

After login
[image: after]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### The first question

###### Short answer:

you must call the selector function with `useSelector` hook. you are calling it directly in your `<h5>` element. so it's not working.

```
const TopBar = () => {
  const username = useSelector(() => store.getState().userNameRecuder.name)

  return(
    <h5>{username}</h5>
  )
}
```

###### Long answer with best practices:

You need to create a [selector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector-examples) and use it in your component to re-render your component after the state changes.

In the selector.js

```
const selectUsername = (state) => state.userNameRecuder.name

export selectUsername;
```

Now, in your **Topbar** component, you need to implement the `useSelector` hook:

```
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {selectUsername} from 'store/selectors';

function TopBar () {
  
  const username = useSelector(selectUsername)

  return (
    <p>username</p>
  )
}
```

Updating the state with proper action (to update username) will cause a re-render in the **Topbar** component to get the new username from the store.

##### The second question

There are many great ways to persist data for example storing them on `cookies`, `localStorage` or using third-party libraries like [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist), and so on...
take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065338/how-to-persisting-data-in-a-react-redux-web-app).

Answer (score 1):

It works based on @novonimo's answer. Even without apart selector.js. Just connect the redux state with the component's state by using `useSelector` hooks, so the component will automatically re-rendered when the redux state changes.

```html
const TopBar = () => {
      const userName = useSelector(() => store.getState().userNameRecuder.name);
      
      return(
        ...
        <h5>userName</h5>
        ...
      )
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your nice answer, actually  the "() => store.getState().userNameRecuder.name" is the selector but implicitly defined in your useSelector  hooks. separating selectors will help in case of changing store object or for debugging